# How can I lower my latency? (Powerline)

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, powerline-networking

How do I lower my latency using a powerline connection?

```
C:\Users\David>ping 192.168.1.254 -t -l 25500

Pinging 192.168.1.254 with 25500 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=25500 time=24ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=25500 time=24ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=25500 time=22ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=25500 time=25ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=25500 time=29ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=25500 time=33ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=25500 time=18ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=25500 time=25ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=25500 time=31ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=25500 time=32ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.254:
    Packets: Sent = 10, Received = 10, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 18ms, Maximum = 33ms, Average = 26ms
```

This isn't too bad, but I'm looking suggestions for improvement as I am interested in online gaming, and do not have an option of running a cable to the router.

I have a TPLink AV200 (or TL-PA211) powerline adapter. It should offer 200Mbps speeds. However I'm not interested in bandwidth speed - but low latency.

Any ideas? WiFi has proved to be horrible so far.

Comment: What kind of signal strength are you seeing in the adapter?

Comment: @cmorse Any ideas on how I can tell the strength? It says the speed is 100Mbps, but that doesn't say much. I'll need some software to test it out.

Comment: It looks like in the UI it's under the "quality" column.

Comment: @cmorse 20-40% : 34 Mbps

Comment: That's pretty low quality values. You should get a better ping time if you can raise that number. I tried to find some info on techniques to improve it, but I came up empty handed. maybe someone else knows.

Comment: At both the router end and the computer end are the powerline adapters plugged into any extension leads or socket multipliers? Can you try other sockets to check for interference or bad cabling?

Comment: Are you running wifi-N over 2.4ghz?  As you increase the Ghz, the wall penetration is greatly reduced.  Running 802.11N or AC over 2.4Ghz with wide channels is likely your best bet.  I get anywhere between 1-10ms pings from my 5-year old Airport Extreme (running G/N over 2.4Ghz) with 4 walls in between (seems to depend on movement and distance).